# Is it possible to recover a tar.xz file with the wrong hex header?

Tags: compression, 7-zip, tar

I have a compressed file in tar.xz format, when I try to open it with 7zip it gives the following error:

Cannot open the file as [xz] archive
Errors: Is no archive.

I checked the file in a hex editor and found that the header of the file corresponds to the jpg format. Here is a image of the hex code:
[image]

Is it possible to recover this file?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Where is the file coming from? Perhaps it's actually a jpg file (or some other file format) and was simply incorrectly name with the .xz? In that case simply rename to have the correct file extension and open with the appropriate program.

Comment: It is a file from a university assignment.
I have tried to change the file extension to jpg, but it gives an error, it says the file is damaged.

Comment: I think it's possible that the file is corrupt. What's the assignment supposed to be for (figuring out corrupted files?...)? Possible to share the file so others can check it?